# Weapon progress in Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I have maxed out several weapons on MW3 but when you look at the gun it says I have not reached the max progression for the gun. For example, my AK-47 has every category maxed out for kills and level 31 max but it says progression level 13 out of 15.

How do I max out the progression level of a weapon?

Comment: Did you also complete all the weapon attachment challenges like kills with grenade launcher, hybrid sights, shotgun, etc?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. Total kills total headshots all the attachments everything. I have multiple weapons I've done this with but not at the top "progress" level so I have no idea what I'm missing

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming by "progression" you're referring challenges completed. There are two "hidden" challenges (Weapon Veteran and Weapon Master - not to be confused with Weapon Mastery) for each weapon that are not revealed until you prestige at least once. These are the ones that unlock weapon titles and emblems, and require more kills and headshots (2500 kills for Weapon Veteran III and 1250 headshots Weapon Master III). I'm not sure if the challenges can be completed without entering prestige mode, but I know you can make progress - I unlocked the silver SPAS-12 emblem, which is unlocked at Weapon Veteran II (1000 kills), before entering prestige mode the first time.

Comment: Thanks that is it. I just sat at level 80 for months and just played to max everything out. I did the prestige the other day and noticed those new categories so now I know what the deal was. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. Would you mind accepting the answer as correct? There should be a check-mark button.